# Android: App going to background on Xiaomi Redmi Phone on activity's finish()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back-stack, xiaomi

I'm working on a E-commerce app and I'm facing this weird issue in Xiaomi phone,

So whenever my an activity's finish() method is called the app goes into background, it doesn't crash, nor does it give an exception it just goes into background and when i open the app from task manager it doesn't restart, it just starts from the page where it should be after the top activity finishes.

I have trying to find out why this is happening but with no luck i found nothing, sometimes when i do a fresh install of the app it works fine for sometime and after that it happens every-time.

Below are details of the App and Phone

- Phone - Xiaomi Redmi Note 4
- Screen Size - 1080x1920
- Ram - 3598 MB
- Internal Storage - 52.16 GB
- Processor - Snapdragon 625 2.02 GHz
- Android Version - 7.0
- compileSdkVersion - 28
- minSdkVersion - 18
- targetSdkVersion - 28

Below is the log of app when it goes into background

```
2019-11-11 19:29:20.894 14025-14025/com.myapp W/GoogleTagManager: Multiple macros active for macroName pgCancel
2019-11-11 19:29:20.913 1902-1902/? D/StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s > disable2<q i n g r >
2019-11-11 19:29:20.917 1617-2058/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2019-11-11 19:29:20.917 2162-2162/? D/Launcher.Lifecycle: onWindowFocusChanged:true,UserHandle{0},cf92b6c,false
2019-11-11 19:29:20.922 2162-2579/? D/Launcher: get showing item successandroid.graphics.Bitmap@1177c13
2019-11-11 19:29:20.924 471-2736/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-11-11 19:29:20.963 2748-5469/? D/GameBoosterService: onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.miui.home', mForegroundUid=10028, mForegroundPid=2162, mLastForegroundPackageName='com.myapp', mLastForegroundUid=10109, mLastForegroundPid=14025, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
2019-11-11 19:29:20.964 1617-2058/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:1244024
2019-11-11 19:29:20.967 2162-2162/? D/Launcher.Lifecycle: onResume:UserHandle{0},cf92b6c,true
2019-11-11 19:29:20.967 2162-2536/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread resumed
2019-11-11 19:29:20.967 2162-2266/? D/Launcher: disableStatusBarClock:false
2019-11-11 19:29:20.967 2162-2536/? I/RenderThread: All controllers paused.
2019-11-11 19:29:20.968 2162-2536/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread paused, waiting for signal
2019-11-11 19:29:20.968 2162-2162/? D/Launcher_DesktopWallpaperManager: adapterHomeToWallpaperAsync in launcher resume
2019-11-11 19:29:20.968 2162-2162/? D/Launcher_DesktopWallpaperManager: adaptHomeToWallpaperAsync
2019-11-11 19:29:20.968 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_StaticWallpaper: current wallpaper is static wallpaper
2019-11-11 19:29:20.987 5238-5238/? D/TouchAssistant: topActivity.getPackageName(),packageName:com.miui.home
2019-11-11 19:29:20.987 5238-5238/? D/TouchAssistant: onTopAppChanged packageName:com.miui.home
2019-11-11 19:29:21.019 14025-14025/com.myapp V/GoogleTagManager: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
2019-11-11 19:29:21.020 14025-14025/com.myapp I/Hansel: app did move to background
2019-11-11 19:29:21.064 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_WallpaperManagerCompatVL: getWallpaperColorMode, colorMode=0
2019-11-11 19:29:21.064 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_StaticWallpaper: current wallpaper is static wallpaper
2019-11-11 19:29:21.094 1617-1627/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17550(1156KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(13MB) LOS objects, 30% free, 36MB/52MB, paused 1.925ms total 138.015ms
2019-11-11 19:29:21.168 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_WallpaperManagerCompatVL: getStatusBarColorMode, statusbarWidth=1080, statusbarHeight=60, statusBarColorMode=0
2019-11-11 19:29:21.168 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_StaticWallpaper: current wallpaper is static wallpaper
2019-11-11 19:29:21.217 2162-2162/? E/Launcher: changeViewByFsGestureState,  view=FitSystemWindowView,  alpha=1.0,  scale=1.0
2019-11-11 19:29:21.218 2162-2162/? E/Launcher: changeViewByFsGestureState,  view=ShortcutMenuLayer,  alpha=1.0,  scale=1.0

    --------- beginning of system
2019-11-11 19:29:21.224 1617-1703/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.myapp/com.myapp.Test.activity.MyActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2045 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:897 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1460 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2635 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:368 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:445 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:198 
2019-11-11 19:29:21.228 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
2019-11-11 19:29:21.228 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0]  -> ForcedResizableInfoActivityController [0xdb6e5df, P1] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
2019-11-11 19:29:21.228 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent) duration: 22 microseconds, avg: 299
2019-11-11 19:29:21.235 2162-2361/? D/Launcher_WallpaperManagerCompatVL: getIsCurrentWallpaperScrollable, isCurrentWallpaperScrollable=false
2019-11-11 19:29:21.235 2162-2162/? D/Launcher_DesktopWallpaperManager: adaptHomeToWallpaper, notify everyone
2019-11-11 19:29:21.244 1617-1703/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:1244303
2019-11-11 19:29:21.246 2162-2274/? D/Launcher_StaticWallpaper: current wallpaper is static wallpaper
2019-11-11 19:29:21.250 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
2019-11-11 19:29:21.251 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0]  -> ForcedResizableInfoActivityController [0xdb6e5df, P1] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
2019-11-11 19:29:21.251 1902-1902/? D/EventBus: [1902, u0] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent) duration: 22 microseconds, avg: 297
2019-11-11 19:29:21.263 2162-2162/? I/AssistHolderView: dispatchDraw
2019-11-11 19:29:21.294 14025-14581/com.myapp I/BranchSDK: returned {}
2019-11-11 19:29:21.295 2971-3148/? W/QCNEJ: |CORE| CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2019-11-11 19:29:21.295 2748-2748/? I/BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
2019-11-11 19:29:21.296 2138-2138/? E/QtiImsExtUtils: getConfigForPhoneId subId is invalid
2019-11-11 19:29:21.296 2138-2138/? E/QtiImsExtUtils: isCarrierConfigEnabled bundle is null
2019-11-11 19:29:21.298 1902-1902/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2019-11-11 19:29:21.300 1902-1902/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
```

Please Help.

Comment: Could you explain, how is this different than documented Android behavior? Your `Activity` is finishing, and it sounds like it is indeed gone. When you resume the app, it may start over from an initial state, or it may resume where you left off (if the OS hasn't culled the app in order to free resources). Just because your app leaves the screen doesn't mean the OS is going to try to kill it. To the contrary, it's going to try to preserve its state for as long as possible, in case the user wants to return to it.

Comment: @greeble31 This is not the only activity in the task/back stack, when i finish() one activity the activity below it in the task should come to top, this happens but the app also goes to background.